# location key in UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey is not getting set

Tags: ios, core-location, ibeacon, appdelegate

I am monitoring a CLBeaconRegion and my didEnterRegion and didExitRegion callbacks are getting called when the app is in the background as well as when it is terminated (by user-swipe-up).  However, the UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.location is nil when the app is woken up.

Here's my AppDelegate code:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    var beaconDelegate: BeaconDelegate = BeaconDelegate()

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        if launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.location] != nil {
            var regionCounter = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "regionCounter") as! Int
            regionCounter += 5
            UserDefaults.standard.set(regionCounter, forKey: "regionCounter")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        }
        return true
    }
    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
       UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }      
    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }
}
```

And here's my BeaconDelegate and it's didEnterRegion:

```
class BeaconDelegate: NSObject {

    var locationManager: CLLocationManager

    override init() {

        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = 1

        super.init()
    }
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didEnterRegion region: CLRegion){

        var regionCounter = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "regionCounter") as! Int
        regionCounter += 1
        UserDefaults.standard.set(regionCounter, forKey: "regionCounter")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

        // Create Local Notification
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent.init()
        content.title = "Beacon Region"
        content.body = body
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 3, repeats: false)
        let identifier = "MyLocalNotification"
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier,
                                    content: content, trigger: trigger)
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.add(request, withCompletionHandler: { (error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Cannot add notification, error: \(error)")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

regionCounter is set to 0 in UserDefaults in my RootViewController.  When my didEnterRegion is called from the foreground or background, regionCounter is incremented by 1.  But the local notification shows that it is also incremented only by 1 (and not by 5) when the app is woken up.

How is it that the location key is not set but my didEnterRegion is called?

Comment: If you print out the launchOptions in a log line (viewable from XCode -> Devices -> {your device} ), what keys are present?

Comment: When the app is woken up, I don't see anything in the log. Does it write to log when it is in the background?  Also, I don't see console log in Xcode->Devices->MyDevice, so I looked at the Console application.

Comment: Here is how you show the logs in XCode: http://imgur.com/a/kx3MI

Comment: Thanks for showing how to see the logs in Xcode.  However, the log from the app doesn't get written in the background.  I do see system messages which show the being woken up in background.

Comment: But I changed my appDelegate code that checked for the location key and saved it in UserDefaults.  Later, when I open the app, I print out the UserDefaults. And now I do see that the location key is being set. Now I simply check it like this: if (launchOptions != nil) and loop thru the launchOptions keys. Thanks for your help!